# How to get data from 3 related entities using LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a student class, program class and session class. I want to select a student on the basis of his **rollno**, **sessionName**, **programName** and **password**.
program and session classes have one to many relationship with student class.

This is Session Class.

```
public class Session
    {
        [Key]
        public int SessionID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string SessionName { get; set; }

        //Relationship ------- Navigational Properties -------------------------------
        public virtual List<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Program> Programs { get; set; }
    }
```

This is program class.

```
public class Program
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProgramID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string ProgramName { get; set; }

        //Relationship ------- Navigational Properties -------------------------------
        public virtual List<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

    }
```

And this is Student Class.

```
public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(35)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string CNIC { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int RollNo { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public bool Graduated { get; set; }
        public bool Expelled { get; set; }

        //Relationship ------- Navigational Properties -------------------------------
        public virtual List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
        public virtual List<StudentMessage> Messages { get; set; }

        public Session Session { get; set; }
        public Program Program { get; set; }
        public Grade Grade { get; set; }
        public Attendance Attendance { get; set; }
        public StudentContact StudentContact { get; set; }
        public StudentMessage StudentMessage { get; set; }

    }
```

Now how do I select student's username who has given specific rollno, sessionName, programName, password using LINQ Query Syntax and using LINQ Method syntax?

In database, Student Table contains SessionID and ProgramID.

I know "Join" is used to extract data from multiple tables but i don't know how to use it in LINQ Syntax.

Comment: Do you have any plan, for change in design other wise above answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
var list = dbContext.Students
    .Where(e=>e.RollNo == 10)
    .Where(e=>e.Password == "password")
    .Where(e=>e.Session.SessionName == "SessionName")
    .Where(e=>e.Session.ProgramName == "ProgramName")
    .Select(e=> e.UserName)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You didn't understand my question :)

Comment: Isn't a single `Where`, together with multiple `&&` much more performant than tons of single `Where`s?

Comment: It does not matter, their pair is one